# Transform SQL ResultSet to json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

I am using postgresql for my webapplication. I am new to this Postgresql-json. I Just want to get the select query result in the form of json structure.
Here are my details:

```
create table sample(id serial, info jsonb);
insert into sample("info") values('{"person": {"phone": 9804484234,"name":{"firstname":"Alice", "lastname":"bob"}, "empId": "E067", "age":25}');
```

select query:

```
select "info"->'person'->>'lastname' from sample;
```

result: bob

but I want to get the above result along with the json nodes like below:

```
result: {"person":
          {"name":
            {"lastname":"bob"}
          }
        }
```

could any body tell me how to get my expected result structure from database.

Comment: Hello All, Please let me know if my query is not clear. I will provide more details if required.

Comment: Could you please some body tell me, Is this possible or not?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense from the point of view of why you would want to do that. If you were trying to get the entire json document for someone with the lastname bob that would make sense, or what your code currently does which is parse the json for the lastname, makes sense, but why you would want just the json the way you are asking doesn't make sense and there is no way to easily do that in postgres. json_extract_path comes close to what you are asking for though.

Comment: Hello Michael, Thanks for the reply. I just wanted to make sure to get the data along with the json structure to send it to the client side. We are using GWT at client side which will accepts json data to display in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

will be much more simple to have:

**A- a normal postgresSQL database and transform response to json.**

- A1. store a normal SQL DB (and no postgres sql json)
- A2. retrieve a SQL resultSet  (select query)
- A3. convert resultset into json with this code

  ```
  public class SOF_36861985 {

             public static JSONArray toJson(ResultSet res) throws Exception {
                  JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                  while (res.next()) {
                      int size = res.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                          obj.put( res
                                  .getMetaData()
                                  .getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                                  .toLowerCase(), 
                                  res.getObject(i + 1));
                          array.put(obj);
                      }
                  }
                  return array;
              }

      }
  ```

**or**

**B. Use mongoDB that is json native database**

- B1. Store datas in mongoDB as json
- B2. query mongoDB will return json resultset

**Comparation of Solution A versus Solution B**

Solution A : sql
+ does not force you to have a new DB, you will continue with postgressql
- will make a convertion from ResultSet to Json
- will have static schema in SQL database (no dynamic schema as in nosql)

Solution B: mongo
- makes change of DB, that is production dependant... and has impact on infrastructure....
+ is json native DB
+ is probably a new DB  for you, you will have a learning time to master it
(will take more time to setup, install, dev...)

Answer (score 1):

You can reproduce the path you are following as a string constant, provided the  path is fixed.

```
select '{"person":{"name":{"lastname":"' ||
(info->'person'->'name'->>'lastname') ||
'"}}}'as val  from sample;
```

Comment: I am using the above syntax but i did not get any proper out put. In the console it is showing 1 row but no output.

Comment: Yes I got the output but is this the only way to get json output? because I have lot of nested json data. I can not go to each node.

Comment: Unfortunately, JSON has no DOM, no XPath or something similar. Contrary to XML which is document format JSON is geared to be a lightweight message format rather then storage option.  Postrgesql itself has no methods to operate on JSON paths,  kinda get-path-to-root.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT json_build_object("person", 
  json_build_object("name", 
   json_build_object("lastname", 
    (info->'person'->'name'->>'lastname')))) 
AS val FROM sample;
```